# Highlight part of text based on a given offset, html

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the best option for achieving dynamic text highlighting based on a given offset? That is I want to be able show part of text that I am showing in a field highlighted based on a predefined range.

For example consider the following text:

"desired output for range (0,13)".

I want to show it like:

"`desired output` for range (0,13)".

Is this possible through Javascript? If not, what do you recommend?

Comment: do you mean "highlighted" as if I selected some text with the cursor?

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to highlight with cursor. I want to show a piece of text specified in a range highlighted. This range is being loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went and tried this out in a jsfiddle (this uses client-side Javascript), with a solution for native Javascript as well as jQuery. Note that I did use the `<code>` tag to achieve it and you could use a different tag if you don't want the regular styling that comes with the `<code>` tag. I don't know of a solution that doesn't involve the usage of some new HTML element though (which is what I used).

http://jsfiddle.net/1jdmvgod/2/